# Update a Row in Xml File

Tags: c#, xml

I want to update an XML file status When date is changing

```
if (DateTime.Parse(dsUpdate.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString()) <= DateTime.Now)
{
    XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(fi.FullName);    
    XElement upd = (from doc in xDoc.Descendants("sysInfo")
                    select doc).Single();
    upd.Element("Status").Value = "Updated";
    xDoc.Save(fi.FullName);                           
}
```

I am using this but somehow it doesn't work.The status of the file is not updated as the date changes. after loading the file it jumps to the catch block 
and nothing happen the status remains the same.

This is the XML file I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<System>
    <SysInfo>
        <InstallDate>2/11/2015 2:26:21 PM</InstallDate>
        <UpdateDate>2/12/2015 2:26:21 PM</UpdateDate>
        <Status>Installed</Status>
    </SysInfo>
</System>
```

Comment: "it jumps to the catch block" - well, what exception got thrown?

Comment: Additionally, `(from doc in xDoc.Descendants("sysInfo") select doc).Single();` would be more clearly written as just `xDoc.Descendants("sysInfo").Single()`. You don't *have* to write a query expression...

Comment: post the XML file you are using. You probably have more than one element with name "sysInfo" or that element has no child called "Status".

Comment: sequence contains no element

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<System>
  <SysInfo>
    <InstallDate>2/11/2015 2:26:21 PM</InstallDate>
    <UpdateDate>2/12/2015 2:26:21 PM</UpdateDate>
    <Status>Installed</Status>
  </SysInfo>
</System>

Comment: Sorry got it I am not considering case-sensitive character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Element names are case-sensitive. Use

```
XElement upd = (from doc in xDoc.Descendants("SysInfo")
                select doc).Single();
```

Or as proposed by @JonSkeet :

```
XElement upd = xDoc.Descendants("SysInfo").Single();
```

Comment: Same exception again

Comment: @AnoopMishra Did you post your entire xml file? Or did you remove some namespaces? There must be something else going on. Are you sure you open the right file?

Comment: sorry the problem is in tag SysInfo I am using wrong tag